# Will installing Workflow Manager for Sharepoint 2013 affect any 2010 workflows that are currently running?

Tags: workflow, workflow-manager, workflow2013, workflow-manager-farm

I have a SharePoint Server Farm with the following Farm architecture
1. Server1 : Database Server
2. Server2 : WFE Server
3. Server3 : Search Application Host Server

Now I am trying to install Workflow Manager in the fourth server which is not connected to the farm. Will this installation cause any problem in the workflows that are already running on the Server2 ? Will I get errors like "workflow failed on starting" etc ?

Answer (score 1):

No... They are 2 different Frameworks. SP2010 Workflows are executed by SharePoint and SP2013 Workflows are executed by the WFM. There is no overlap.